# Getting Tiles' put-list-attribute to work with a Thymeleaf template

Tags: tiles, thymeleaf

I am trying to get **Apache Tiles**' `put-list-attribute` to work with **Thymeleaf**.

Here is what I tried:

*From Tiles config:*

```
<put-list-attribute name="jsFilesList">
 <add-attribute value="/js/libs/jquery-1.8.1.js"/>
  <add-attribute value="/js/libs/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js"/>
  <add-attribute value="/js/libs/bootstrap.js"/>
</put-list-attribute>
```

*From thymleaf template:*

```
<script th:each="jsFile : ${jsFilesList}" th:src="@{${jsFile}}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Nothing is rendered... **It seems the list is empty from the thymeleaf template point of view...**

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Tiles attributes are not by default available in the request scope. They live in their own tiles scope.

In jsps, to expose a tiles attribute from its scope to the request scope do the following:

`<%@ taglib prefix="tilesx" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles-extras" %>
<tilesx:useAttribute id="jsFilesList" name="jsFilesList"/>`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Good point. However I don't think Thymeleaf as a special namespace for that. It should work without changing the namespace. I am sure it has to do with the syntax in the Thymeleaf template...